# Blackberry simulator - receive an sms in my Blackberry application without notifying inbox

Tags: blackberry

Here I am using the Blackberry simulator 8520. I want to receive an sms in my Blackberry application without notifying the inbox (silently).

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        try
        {
            DatagramConnection dc =(DatagramConnection)Connector.open("sms://");

            for(;;)
            { 
                Datagram d = dc.newDatagram(dc.getMaximumLength());
                dc.receive(d);
                byte[] bytes = d.getData();
                String address=new String(bytes);
                String msg = new String(bytes);
                String message=msg.toString();
                add(new RichTextField(message));
                add(new RichTextField(address));
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();   
         }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SMS message will have to be sent to a port other than port 0 (the default)
`Connector.open("sms://:1500");` and your program will have to be listening on the port when the message arrives. If you send an SMS message from a BlackBerry to a port other than 0 it is actually sent to 0 or the port specified so if there is no server listening to the port the message is delivered to the inbox.

Comment: is this port number 1500 is fixed?actually iam also trying this.my requirement is iam sending the sms from my application it should be stored in my inbox and outbox not in general inbox and outbox.if u have any idea plz give your suggestion

Comment: No, you can use any port number not alread in use. I'm not sure I know what you mean by "it should be stored in my inbox and outbox not in general inbox and outbox."